# The value contained in %rsp register

Tags: assembly, x86-64

So I'm dealing with these Assembly codes:

[image]

With the address of ***%rsp = 0x7FFFFFFFDE88*** before calling **foo**

After calling the function **foo**, a new element is pushed to the stack frame %rsp so the address of %rsp is now should be ***0x7FFFFFFFDE80*** and it should contain the address of the instruction right after the *callq*  instruction. In the entry of the function foo, it sub $0x38 to %rsp to push more elements, so %rsp is now ***0x7FFFFFFFDE48***. I have some question with the instruction *67e*: When movq $0x2, (%rsp), is it moved to the address of ***0x7FFFFFFFDE48***, which is the start of %rsp?

Comment: Yes, there and the following 7 bytes of course.

Comment: So the return address that is needed for foo to come back to the main function is still in 0x7FFFFFFFDE80 right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And the address of 0x7FFFFFFFDE88 is unused as it doesn't contain anything, is that correct?

Comment: It is unused padding, yes. Of course memory always contains something, it's just some random garbage in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here's what the stack would look like:

```
0x7FFFFFFFDE48: 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x7FFFFFFFDE50: 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x7FFFFFFFDE58: 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x7FFFFFFFDE60: 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x7FFFFFFFDE68: ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? (Your code never wrote to this memory)
0x7FFFFFFFDE70: ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? (Your code never wrote to this memory)
0x7FFFFFFFDE78: ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? (Your code never wrote to this memory)
0x7FFFFFFFDE80: D5 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 (return address)
0x7FFFFFFFDE88: ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? (Your code never wrote to this memory)
```

Notice that at line `6d0: e8 95 ff ff ff callq 66a <foo>` the address after that is `6d5`. If you subtract `6d5` from `66a` you get `0xFFFFFF95` (which when sign-extended is the relative distance between the first line of code in `foo`).